# R shinyApp() maximize used display space

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm working on a shiny app that will be used in RStudio Window mode. I'm looking for solutions to increase the size of the window that opens when running `shinyApp(ui,server)`. I am **not** looking to toggle fullscreen mode, just increase the size of that window that is currently a square filling maybe half the width of may available screen estate. I'd like to be able to utilize the full screen width without the user having to manually change the window size.

Solutions I found were about fullscreen, or didn't work, such as e.g `shinyApp(ui,server, options = list(width=1500, height = 1080))`. I tried running it as `runGadget(ui, server, viewer = dialogViewer("", width = 1500, height = 1080))` but for one, it just doesn't look as nice and I think a separate window is more user-friendly than a RStudio dialog window, and second I still couldn't get it to actually use almost all available screen estate, it would just stop doing anything with further increasing size values after a certain point.